# Variable transformation for factor analysis

Tags: data-transformation, factor-analysis

When conducting a factor analysis, we need to check the normality and constant variance assumption of the original variables.
If there is HSK existing in the data, can I do different transformations(for example log transformation to x1, squared x2...) to different variables and then conduct the analysis?
Or I should do the same transformation to all variables?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: To be sure to understand, are you talking of pure FA or just PCA-related methods?

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly apply different transformations to different variables, but it will change the meaning of the results.  A key assumption in factor analysis is that the observed measurements are linear combinations of the underlying factors (plus noise).  Transforming the observed measurements could have a big influence on the results.